# This code is getting unreachable code, and I'm not sure why

Tags: java, compiler-errors, unreachable-code

Sorry for the large amount of code, but I'm not sure why

```
int timesWon;
```

is getting a unreachable code error on line 90.
Anything that is put on line 90 is unreachable code, meaning anything after it isn't readable.

This is my code for a game of craps for an assignment:

```
package homework2_3;

import java.security.*;

public class Craps 
{
    static enum score
    {
        win, lose
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //random Number for a dice roll
        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
        //ints for the totals on the two dice
        int dice1;
        int dice2;
        //array for times won/lost
        score[] total = new score[1000000];
        //int for the score of the first throw, if it was not an imediate win or loss
        int throw1Score = 0;

        //count how many times a win or loss happened at each roll from 1-21
        int[] rollWon = new int[22];
        int[] rollLost = new int[22];

        //loop for each game from 1-1000000
        for(int indexGame = 1; 1 <= 1000000; indexGame++)
        {
            //loop for each throw within a game
            for(int indexThrow = 1; total[indexGame] != score.win || total[indexGame] != score.lose; indexThrow++)
            {
                //get the total of blips on the dice
                dice1 = random.nextInt(6) + 1;
                dice2 = random.nextInt(6) + 1;
                //check if the throw total in throw 1
                if(indexThrow == 1)
                {
                    //check if throw 1 is an instant win
                    if((dice1 + dice2) == 7 || (dice1 + dice2) == 11)
                    {
                        total[indexGame] = score.win;
                        rollWon[indexThrow]++;
                    }
                    //check if throw 1 is an instant loss
                    else if((dice1 + dice2) == 2 || (dice1 + dice2) == 3 || (dice1 + dice2) == 12)
                    {
                        total[indexGame] = score.lose;
                        rollLost[indexThrow]++;
                    }
                    //get your "point"
                    else
                    {
                        throw1Score = dice1 + dice2;
                    }
                }
                //anything other than throw 1
                else
                {
                    //check if you "made your point"
                    if((dice1 + dice2) == throw1Score)
                    {
                        total[indexGame] = score.win;
                        if(indexThrow <= 20)
                        {
                            rollWon[indexThrow]++;
                        }
                        else if(indexThrow > 20)
                        {
                            rollWon[21]++;
                        }
                    }
                    //check if you rolled a 7 (lost)
                    else if((dice1 + dice2) == 7)
                    {
                        total[indexGame] = score.lose;
                        if(indexThrow <= 20)
                        {
                            rollLost[indexThrow]++;
                        }
                        else if(indexThrow > 20)
                        {
                            rollLost[21]++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //ints to add up all the wins and losses in the array of scores
        int timesWon;
        int timesLost;
        //loop for the adding
        for(int winLossCheck = 1; winLossCheck <= 1000000; winLossCheck++)
        {
            if(total[winLossCheck] == score.win)
            {
                timesWon++;
            }
            if(total[winLossCheck] == score.lose)
            {
                timesLost++;
            }
        }
        //print the total times you won/lost
        System.out.println("you won " + timesWon + " times, and you lost " + timesLost + " times");
    }
}
```

As far as I can tell, everything is logically correct and syntactically correct.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: `for(int indexGame = 1; 1 <= 1000000; indexGame++)` is an infinite loop, 1 will always be less than 1000000. Maybe you meant `indexGame <= 1000000`?

Comment: Note that enums are types and should be named with "Pascal case" (`Score`), and enum values are constants and should be named uppercase (`WIN, LOSE`).

Answer (score 1):

`1 <= 1000000` is always `true`

Answer (score 0):

You have a for loop in which the condition is `1 <= 1000000`. This loop will not exit, thus making all code after the loop unreachable. Change the the condition to something where the code will exit.

For example:

```
for(int i = 1; i<=10; i++) {
   System.out.println(i);
}
```

This code will print out the integers from 1-10. However if I create another for loop with a condition that is always true like 0<7. Since the loop won't end, all code after it is unreachable. Change your for loop to have a condition that won't always be true, so the program will continue.